# "Probability Based" Time Delay of Arrival Algorithm Producing Weird Results?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've written the following algorithm designed to solve the Time Delay of Arrival problem through a "brute force" method. The problem is as follows: given the *known* locations of three receivers in a plane, and the propagating speed of some signal, determine the location of the signal source knowing only the times at which each receiver "saw" the signal.

The algorithm works by assuming the source to be within a 1000 x 1000 kilometre square area, and then iterating (with 1 km "resolution") over every possible location, calculating the time to travel to each receiver and determining which location matches most closely with the known delay of arrival between each receiver (so, for each location [x,y], I calculate the time to arrive to receivers 1, 2, and 3, then determine how close time to arrive at 1 - time to arrive at 2 is to the live data, and similarly for the combinations 1 - 3 and 2 - 3 (ignoring other possible combinations, for simplicity).

Here's the problem: it's *highly* unlikely each signal event is coming from the same direction. However, my code seems to suggest every event is at [0,0]. While it is technically *possible* that this is the case, it is far more likely that there is something wrong with my code, so for the purposes of this question let's assume that to be the case. Perhaps I've made some obvious mistake here?

```
#define c   299792
#define statn1x 3.00000
#define statn1y 3.60000
#define statn2x 2.10000
#define statn2y 2.10000
#define statn3x 0.96000
#define statn3y 3.60000

void findProb(double alpha, double gamma, double beta){

    int x,y;
    double thld = DBL_MAX;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j){

            double alphaEst = sqrt(pow(i-statn1x,2) + pow(j-statn1y,2)) / c;
            double betaEst  = sqrt(pow(i-statn1x,2) + pow(j-statn1y,2)) / c;
            double gammaEst = sqrt(pow(i-statn1x,2) + pow(j-statn1y,2)) / c;
            std::cout << i << "," << j << "\n";
            if( std::max(std::max(fabs((alphaEst-betaEst) - alpha), fabs((alphaEst-gammaEst)-beta) ), fabs((betaEst-gammaEst)-gamma)) -
                std::min(std::min(fabs((alphaEst-betaEst) - alpha), fabs((alphaEst-gammaEst)-beta) ), fabs((betaEst-gammaEst)-gamma)) < thld){

                thld = std::max(std::max(fabs((alphaEst-betaEst) - alpha), fabs((alphaEst-gammaEst)-beta) ), fabs((betaEst-gammaEst)-gamma)) -
                std::min(std::min(fabs((alphaEst-betaEst) - alpha), fabs((alphaEst-gammaEst)-beta) ), fabs((betaEst-gammaEst)-gamma));

                x = i;
                y = j;

            }

        }
    }

    //std::cout << x << "," << y << "\n";

}

void localize(){

    ROOT::RDataFrame tdoa("D","./coincidences.root");

    vector<double> alpha, beta, gamma;

    tdoa.Foreach([&](double delay){ alpha.push_back(delay); },{"x"});
    tdoa.Foreach([&](double delay){ beta.push_back(delay); },{"y"});
    tdoa.Foreach([&](double delay){ gamma.push_back(delay); },{"z"});

    int iter = std::min(std::min(alpha.size(), beta.size()), gamma.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < iter; ++i){

        findProb(alpha[i], beta[i], gamma[i]);

    }

}
```

Note the terminology used in this project:

`alpha` refers to time to arrive (ttoa) at station 1 - ttoa station 2.

`gamma` refers to ttoa station 1 - ttoa station 3

`beta` refers to ttoa station 2 - ttoa station 3

`alphaEst` refers to the calculated estimated travel time from some location [x,y] to station 1

`betaEst` refers to the calculated estimated travel time from some [x,y] to station 2

... and likewise for `gammaEst`.

Note that I'm also working now to produce a smaller, reproducible example (if possible). I'll add that as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alphaEst, betaEst and gammaEst are assigned the same values.

```
betaEst = sqrt(pow(i-statn1x,2) + pow(j-statn1y,2)) / c
```

probably it should be

```
betaEst = sqrt(pow(i-statn2x,2) + pow(j-statn2y,2)) / c
```

Comment: Phew! That's it, thanks! It's always the really, really stupid simple things that get me.